# websocket ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: certificate, wss

when some players enter our game, they meet this error in all browsers [image]

We have changed the certificate recently. So I check one player's certificate on our game page,[image]

It is the lastest certificate. So what may cause this problem? Should we do something after change the certificate?

**EDIT1**

Did CDN cache the certificate? After we refresh the CDN, some player can connect to the game immediately.

**EDIT2**

We found the player's browser has such an option "block unsafe certificate", when the option is enabled,  he can't connect to the server and he can connect to server when the option is disabled. We export the intermediate certificate and send it to the player for import. After that, the player can play the game with the option selected.

**EDIT3**

Finally we found the intermediate certificate is right on the nginx side,but on the server side, the ca is missing. After add it, the websocket could work. And When I asked same question on another forum [v2ex](https://www.v2ex.com/t/729631#;),I found a good way to test if the certificate chain is complete. you can visit the site and change the domain and port with your site.

https://cert.catbox.io/api/v1/queryChain?domain=s41001-ad-tanwan.zlgl.17tanwan.com&port=8085

If your server is correct, you will find the server side certificate and the intermediate certificate.If you can't find the intermediate certicate, you need to check your server config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server https://s41001-ad-tanwan.zlgl.17tanwan.com/ provides only the last certificate in the chain, the actual certificate of the server.

This certificate is signed by the intermediate certificate from "RapidSSL TLS DV RSA Mixed SHA256 2020 CA-1" that is valid since 2020-07-16.
If the clients have not updated their browsers/operating systems for some time, they don't have this intermediate certificate, and they report this as an invalid certification authority.

Put the intermediate certificate to the certificate file, and it should fix the problem, since the intermediate certificate is signed by the DigiCert root certificate, that is in the game since 2006. Everyone has it.

You run nginx, right? The `ssl_certificate` instruction in nginx accepts files with certificate chains. This file should have the server certificate first, then the intermediate certificate.

Comment: We checked nginx and find already have put the intermediate certificate. Did CDN cache the certificate? After we refresh the CDN, some player can connect to the game immediately.

Comment: Yes, you do provide the intermediate certificate. Then just ask the players who have problems, to open the page https://s41001-ad-tanwan.zlgl.17tanwan.com/ . It is error 403, but that doesn't matter. Ask them to click on the lock sign in the address line. What is the certificate? May be your web site is blocked by some firewall, that intercepts the traffic and injects its own certificate.

Comment: Finally we found on the nginx side,the intermediate certificate is right. But on the server side, the intermediate certificate is missing.

Comment: @Pan, Are you sure that you added the certificate to the server? I use `openssl s_client` tool to check your certificate, and it still tells me that there is only one certificate. The link that you provided in your question, also shows only one certificate.

Comment: Yes I'm wrong for saying the intermediate certificate is missing. I just asked the backend programmer, he tells me that the server side didn't config for the CA.We test it on another site, so link only show one certificate.